# How to perform a foreach loop over a \def variable

Tags: foreach, def

I want to perform in LaTeX a foreach-loop over a def variable:

```
\def\material{Computer,Internet,Home-Folder}
\begin{itemize}
\foreach \x in {\material} 
{
\item \x
}
\end{itemize}
```

I want to get something like:

- Computer
- Internet
- Home-Folder

but I got:

- Computer,Internet,Home-Folder

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Just remove the braces around `\material`, i.e. `\foreach \x in \material { ... }`